# Callback function's byte parameter has value out of bounds in project Panama function interface

Tags: java, callback, java-native-interface, ffi, project-panama

I'm using the new Foreign function & memory API which is part of project Panama and available in preview in JAVA 19.

This is a simple Java callback function

```
public static byte addFive(byte t) {
    Byte test = (Byte) t;
    return (byte) (Long.valueOf(test) + 5);
}
```

I have a native library function that is called with parameters `addFive` and `(byte) -41`.

```
uint8_t callback_test(uint8_t (*fn)(uint8_t), uint8_t arg) {
    uint8_t res = fn(arg + 1) * 2;
    return res;
}
```

I expect `t` to have value `-40`, and this does show in the Intellij debugger. But when you print it, it prints `216` instead. In addition, casting to `Byte` gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I do realize that the native function is an unsigned int, so the returned value of `216` makes sense. However, a `java byte` should not be allowed that value, so, I expect java to automatically convert it to `-41`.

Is this behavior expected?

What is the correct way to get the unsigned int from the native code passed to the java function as a byte in the range [-128, 127]?

Comment: Could you give it a try with the JDK20 early access build? (https://jdk.java.net/20/) The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` could be caused by a bug that exists in 19 (https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign/pull/720)

Comment: @JornVernee It does work in the JDK20 early access build, so that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was [a bug in JDK19](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8291873) such that there was no value normalization in upcalls.

This is now fixed.